# Having trouble using the mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I haven't used R in a while and I got the opportunity to practice with a new public dataset.  However, the `mutate` function is not behaving the way I am expecting it to and I am confused because this is a supposed to be an easy operation.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(LName = c("DENTON", "CHAMBERS", "BURANDT", "ROTHMAN", "ROSENBERG"), 
               Birthdate = c("02/07/1962", "02/20/1942", "09/16/1958", 
                             "03/28/1994", "04/20/1986"), 
               Gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), 
               PrecinctCode = c(2323L, 2300L, 2341L, 2263L, 1365L), 
               LegislativeDistrict = c(46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 43L), 
               Registrationdate = c("02/14/1992", "10/03/1990", "05/20/1984", "08/14/2012", "08/11/2015"), 
               LastVoted = c("11/08/2016", "11/04/2008", "02/12/2019", "11/08/2016", "11/06/2018"), 
               StatusCode = c("I", "I", "A", "A", "A")), 
               .Names = c("LName", "Birthdate", "Gender", "PrecinctCode", 
                          "LegislativeDistrict", "Registrationdate", "LastVoted", "StatusCode"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I am trying to do is create a new column using mutate and populating it with data and strings to form a particular output.  The output should read as *SEA 43-1365*

The code I am using is:

```
sample_data %>%
   mutate("SEA" & " " & LegislativeDistrict & "-" & PrecinctCode)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.
```

I have tried changing the data formats of some of the columns, I have also tried using the `paste` function. I am kinda stumped regarding what I am doing wrong but I know that it's going to be painfully obvious when someone points it out.

Thank you!

Comment: Ah, you do say you've tried `paste()`. It would be better to show that attempt. `&` just isn't going to work at all, that's not valid R code.

Comment: Yikes.  Thank you.

Comment: In R, `&` is a boolean operator, as in `TRUE & FALSE` would return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you joran,  your comment helped me figure it out.  I will be closing this question when I am allowed to in nine minutes.

Thanks bud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
sample_data %>%
   mutate(newcol = paste("SEA", LegislativeDistrict, "-", PrecinctCode, sep = " "))
```